# JS input value amount doesnt change the value

Tags: javascript

Hey there im on trubbels with setting the bet value someone please can help me with it? Its about this page here: https://stake.com/casino/games/hilo
in here i want to set the bet amount with javascript. Ive already tryed many many ways and houres of googeling but i aint get an sollution for it. BTW im new on javascript so please dont be angry with me for this i guess simple taskthis is what i got already to create the inputfield

[on entering the new value eg with xxx.value=0.00060000 the page resets the value to 0.00000000 after some seconds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qzzcr.png)

```
var b = prompt("Base","0.00000001");
setTimeout(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        var btnSet1 = document.createElement("button");
        btnSet1.textContent = "Set Base bet";
        btnSet1.id = "Base"
        btnSet1.style.position ="absolute";
        btnSet1.style.backgroundColor="white"
        btnSet1.style.left="0";
        btnSet1.style.display="block";
        btnSet1.gridtemplatecolumns="1fr 1fr";
        btnSet1.gridgap="10px";
        btnSet1.style.padding="10px 24px";
        btnSet1.style.left = "0px";
        btnSet1.style.bottom = "45px";
        btnSet1.style.width="200px";
        btnSet1.style.left = "auto";
        btnSet1.style.fontSize="17px";
        btnSet1.style.zIndex = "auto";
        btnSet1.style.margin="4px 2px";
        btnSet1.style.borderColor="black";
        btnSet1.style.borderRadius="4px";
        btnSet1.style.backgroundColor="white";
        btnSet1.addEventListener("click", function(){
            b = prompt("Base");
            setTimeout(function(){console.log("insert amount here")
            },2020);
        },2020)
        document.body.appendChild(btnSet1);
    },2020)
})
```

Comment: Just apply a class that adds all those styles. That's too much styling via direct Javascript.

Comment: thanks for your answer Brett84c my problem is not the style from the inputbox or the box.

Answer (score -1):

The problem of my case is that the entered value doesnt change after entering it and replaces it with the old original value.